# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed ignored in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios7

This code was working well until iOS 7 release. I'm assigning a `UIViewController`, with `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` as `YES`, as the `rootViewController` of an `UINavigationController`. But the TabBar is being shown anyway. Here's the relevant code:

```
Login *lv = [[Login alloc] init];
lv.HowToUseShows = showHowToUse;
lv.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

UINavigationController *BokShelfNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lv];

//... 

UITabBarController *tbController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tbController.viewControllers = @[BokShelfNav,...];
```

Anyone with a similar problem?

Comment: You set the HideBottomBarWhenPushed to YES. Which mean to hide your tabbar when you are presenting this view. If you want your Tabbar to be present there try to remove this line of code `lv.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`.

Comment: Sorry @Priyatham51 I think I didn't make it clear enough, the problem is that the bar **is showing**, and I want it to be hidden.

Comment: Yes same problem I am facing with my existing code.

Comment: @PiyushHirpara good to know I'm not the only one, any ideas how to fix it so far?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found that the order in which methods are called and properties are set has an impact on whether the tab bar is shown.

If I put `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller I'm pushing the tab bar still shows. If I moved it to the `init` method the tab bar hides as it used to on iOS 6.

Comment: This seems to be a much better way to solve this. Reassigned the ticket to you.

Comment: This is nice if the init function is actually called, but for my UITableViewController created by a storyboard, the init function is not getting called.

Comment: `-initWithCoder:` will be called in place of `-init` for Interface Builder objects.

Comment: Almost three years later this helped me. Putting it in the initializer. The official documentation should note this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround I've found is to make the tabBarController start in another tab (`[tbController setSelectedIndex:1];`), and then, in the `viewWillAppear:` method of that tab ViewController do `[tbController setSelectedIndex:0];`

Comment: Yes ..May be it will work for me also, I also noticed that if you are in screen with tab bar and push to the next screen and when you come back to the screen at that time tabbar as hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I have set setSelectedIndex after push statement and it worked.

```
//created tabbar controller object

if(index==0)
    [tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:1];

[self.navigationcontroller pushViewcontroller:tabbarcontroller anmated:YES];
[tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:index];
```

The only issue is if you are showing your controller at 0th index in that it will show. In this case I have first set mt tabbarcontroller's index as 1(different from 0). And its working.

Comment: Yes this should work too, probably both answers are correct, so I'm giving the ticket to you ;).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you got this to work? I have a custom UITabBar and selecting another tab and coming back doesn't work for me...