# TabBars and iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a UITabbarController that I'm pushing another controller on top of using a UINavigationController. On iOS 6 and below, the tabBar of the parent controller slides away and the toolbar of the new view controller is presented. But on iOS 7 the tabBar doesn't animate away even if I run the code `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];`

EDIT - Okay I narrowed my problem to iOS 7 not respecting the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property, I followed the answers in [hidesBottomBarWhenPushed ignored in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047747/hidesbottombarwhenpushed-ignored-in-ios-7) but it didn't work. The view that is pushed has a toolbar with buttons and the buttons are responding to touches, it's just that the tabBar is on top of the toolbar.

Comment: Have you tried UIViewController's `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work.

Comment: hidesBottomBarWhenPushed just isn't listening in iOS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an view not being removed on my custom TabBar.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS7 you need to set the property hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to YES on the presented controller instead of the presenter controller to hides the tabbar.