# Init PageRenderer before it's pushed. (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to Init something on PageRenderer before it's pushed?
I looked documant and it says.

> When a ContentPage is rendered by a Xamarin.Forms application, in iOS
>   the PageRenderer class is instantiated

And I tested it. yes, PageRenderer's constructor is not called before "Push" called.

I want to access it and change ViewController HidesBottomBarWhenPushed to "True", because otherwise that function should not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `HidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property, you can just override it and return the desired value.

So, in your `PageRenderer` implementation, you should do this:

```
public override bool HidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

Apple docs on [hidesBottomBarWhenPushed](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621863-hidesbottombarwhenpushed)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know there is something like this. But unforetunatly it's still not working. maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047747/hidesbottombarwhenpushed-ignored-in-ios-7 this isssue. I have tabbedPage for mainPage and each tab has each Navigation. And putting HidesBottomBarWhenPushed True does not work.

Comment: hm. weird part is that HidesBottomBarWhenPushed getter is not even called. It's not stopped on debug nor print console.

Comment: @BrightLee you need to override HidesBottomBarWhenPushed on the top-most view controller on the tab of the tab controller. In this case, the navigation controller. So, you will need another PageRenderer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replay. I tried ------------------- [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(NavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace XXX
{
 public class NavigationPageRenderer : NavigationRenderer ....................... but this is not working either. nothing happened. Did I do correctly?

Comment: And I did same thing on TabbedPage and ContentPage but none of them works.

Comment: My hierarchy is TabbedPage(4 tabs) - Navigation(each for single contentpage) - ContentPage